# Is there a word for when the light is dusky all day?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for when it is dusk all day? Like in the arctic circle at a certain time of year, the light is dim and red-purple-orange, all day long

Comment: Why the close vote?

Answer (score 1):

Bruno Laeng, "[Blue Noon](http://architecturenorway.no/questions/identity/laeng-blaatime/)," Architecture Norway, 05 Feb, 2015.

This source calls it a "**blue noon**" (note the scare quotes by the author) or "**winter twilight**,"  but no other use cases of the expression could be immediately found.

It's *mørketid* (“dark time” in Norwegian)

[image]
<sup>Blue noon in Vardø, 2014. Photo: Ivan Brodey</sup>

***mørketid* (“dark time” in Norwegian)**

> for a long period during the winter season there is a complete absence of direct sunlight or a pervasive dim light, called *mørketid* (“dark time” in Norwegian); in contrast, in the summer months, there is continuous light as the sun remains above the horizon through the night (i.e., the *midnattsol* or “midnight sun” period)
>   …
>   In the northern hemisphere of Earth, outside the Arctic region (it) is impossible to experience … “**Darkness at Noon**”, as it happens … in the winter
>   …
>   What is special in the Arctic is that the **winter twilight** can last for hours instead for just a few minutes as in most of the inhabited world
>   …
>   in the Arctic winter, these “blues” get further reflected by snow on the ground. Hence in the Arctic, during the winter months, the prevalent light is a blue tint that pervades the whole landscape